# iOS Background service limitations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-service

I would like to know if there are limitations regarding how often I can execute something in the background. I found this library : [background fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) and it says that on the iOS part I cannot execute it more often than 15 minutes.

Are there workarounds for this?

My purpose is to check in the background the available Bluetooth devices detected and to send them to a database.

I only have experience in android and I'm not sure how to convert it to iOS or if it is possible.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not how background fetch is supposed to be used and will probably lead to rejection in the AppStore. My guess is that you want to build some kind of contact tracing system, which will probably not work properly on iOS since background modes are very limited and there are a bunch of restrictions on them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are limitations imposed by iOS.  It will decide when your app is given time to execute background tasks such as a fetch of web data.  It can be more frequent than 15 minutes but on average it may be every 20 minutes at best.  It might be two hours or more.  We are not privy to the algorithm and cannot predict the result.

Known factors are power state, how well your app conforms to the rules and gets its work done in the time allotted, and some measure of how (and when) the user uses your app.  Low battery?  Fewer background tasks allowed.  User never uses the app before 8AM?  Few fetches called overnight.  It's all beyond developer control.

A developer can use a timer to trigger a routine task but it's only relevant if the app stays active in the foreground.